# Remove negative values from nested list

Tags: r

I have following list:

```
 [[1]]
  [1] 0  -1  -2  -3  -4 
 [[2]] 
  [1] 2   1   0  -1  -2
 [[3]]
  [1] 2   3   4   5   6
```

I want to remove negative values from above list. 
I am trying with following code in r

```
  x[ x > 0 ]
```

But, it does not remove negative values.

Comment: That list doesn't look nested. Also `x>0` removes 0 as well (not only negatives).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `lapply` over each list element and select only those values which are greater than or equal to 0.

```
lapply(lst, function(x) x[x >= 0])

#$l1
#[1] 0

#$l2
#[1] 2 1 0

#$l3
#[1] 2 3 4 5 6
```

**Data**

```
lst = list(l1 = c(0,-1,-2,-3,-4),l2 = c(2,1,0,-1,-2), l3 = c(2,3,4,5,6))
```